# Downloading all files from a remote HTTP folder using wget

Tags: shell, wget

I want to download all the `*.gif` files from a particular location. For example, say the location is `http://asdf.com/file/images/*.gif`. When I use:

```
wget -m http://asdf.com/file/images/
```

I get a `403 (permission denied)` error. But when I use:

```
wget -m http://asdf.com/file/images/xyz.gif
```

It works perfectly. There are about 50 images; how can I download them? I can't write 50 `wget` commands

Comment: Do you know the filenames?

Comment: Don't repost your questions.  This is the same as  [Image folder download using wget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131338/image-folder-download-using-wget).

Comment: If you know the filenames this is trivial, especially if they are sequential (image001, image002, etc...)

Comment: @Matthew I think the problem here is this fellow posted the same question on stackoverflow.com and superuser.com. Naturally, someone at stackoverflow migrated the question here and it was duplicated.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.

`wget` cannot know which files exist on the remote server.

Instead, if the server has directory browsing enabled, or if the images are linked somewhere, you can crawl some other page.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why no one has suggested wget -r.  OP is hitting a server that has directory listing disabled, but anyone passing through here should know that wget can handle recursive fetching easily.  It can even filter by file types.

Comment: Points to you for answering my question.  I was indeed passing through and had forgotten about that flag, thanks!

Comment: One warning that I just learned: unless you want to traverse up to parent directories and download the whole damn website, add the `-np` or `--no-parent` flag, so that wget only descends downwards in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You first example is trying to get a directory listing.  The server has directory listing disabled and returning a 403.